# remove post and categories/tags count from right now dashboard widget

Tags: posts, widgets, dashboard

I know it is easily possible to add a post-type count for a custom post type to the right now dashboard widget.

However I wonder if it is also possible to remove stuff from this widget.

E.g. I don't have normal posts on my current wordpress site and I don't need the count to say 0 posts and 0 categories and 0 tags all the time.

Is it possible to remove those counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filter in PHP, so we have to use JavaScript:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-index.php', 'wpse_82132_hide_rows' );

function wpse_82132_hide_rows()
{
    $rows = array (
    #   'posts',
    #   'pages',
        'cats', // meoww!
        'tags',
    #   'comments',
    #   'b_approved',
    #   'b-waiting',
    #   'b-spam',
    );
    $find = '.' . join( ',.', $rows );
    ?>
<script>
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $("#dashboard_right_now").find('<?php echo $find; ?>').parent().addClass('hidden');
});
</script>
    <?php
}
```

#### Result

[image]

To remove the widget completely:

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_82132_remove_rn_dashboard' );

function wpse_82132_remove_rn_dashboard()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
}
```

Comment: It is possible to remove the metabox and add a custom one.

Comment: @CorvanNoorloos see my update.